# How to install ionic framework on my system windows 7?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

Want install ionic framework on my windows system.when i started to install first  have to install Node.js its error showing me warning 1909 could not create shortcut node.js command prompt.ink verify the destination folder exists and that you can access it.Please help me.want install ionic framework on my windows system.

Comment: Did you do what the error message said? Check if the folder exists and if you can access it?

Answer (score 6):

on Windows

Don't forget to install other dependencies before installing ionic http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html

1) Uninstall Node from Control Panel

2) Restart PC

3) Download (MSI Installer) older version of Node from http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.38/ and for 64bit http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.38/x64/

4) Install Node version 0.10.38

5) npm install -g cordova

6) npm install -g ionic

Done!

Note: I don't recommend using the older version. But if newer version don't work sometimes its better to use older version just to try out.

Answer (score 2):

For The installation of Ionic Framework in windows pc. Here Are some Step to Install ionic.

1) First You Have to download nod.js in youre windown system.(below 4.0 version of node.js);

2) after this you have to open node.js command prompt.

3) install cordova and ionic both simultaneously. using below Command.

> $ npm install -g cordova ionic

4) it will take some time to install corodva and ionic in your system. It will depand on your internet connection speed.

5)To Check ionic is completely install or note use below command in node console.

> ionic

To Get More:-  [Info How to Install Ionic Framework in Windows & What is Ionic Framework.](http://www.techsofttutorials.com/how-install-ionic-framework-in-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

Both ionic and cordova are available as node packages that can be installed using node package manager or NPM
npm install ionic cordova -g